# Squaring a list of number in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

So for a homework question in my discrete mathematical modeling class we were asked to make a function in Mathematica which inputs a list and squares each element of that list. It's an easy task and I've already done the following:

```
sqList[list_] = (list)^2;
```

But I want to do this with a "for loop". Here's my code:

```
sqList2[list2_] :=
  (
    For[j = 1, j <= Length[list2], j++,
    (
     list2[j]^2;
     )];
   list2
  );
```

I'm more used to Matlab and am trying to move up the learning curve. This code makes sense to me and will really appreciate any directions in which I should take this. I've tried debugging this code, but like I said I'm not used to this program nor to its stack track. I couldn't find any problems, but it outputs the exact list I input.

Comment: Note that Mathematica has its own StackExchange site at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you want to write loops stick to C or one of those other poor languages which can't do list or array operations.  Learning to write loops in Mathematica is not really learning Mathematica.  Leaving that aside, your loopy code does not assign the result of `list2[j]^2` to anything so Mathematica silently (that's what the trailing `;` does) computes it and carries on.  At the end of the function it returns the input argument (`list2`) unmodified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an example list

```
list = {1, 2, 3};

sqList[list_] := list^2

sqList[list]
```

> {1, 4, 9}

This works because `Power` (**`^`**) is listable:

```
Attributes[Power]
```

> {Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Protected}

To process the list element by element

```
sqList2[list2_] := Module[{squaredlist = {}, j},
  For[j = 1, j <= Length[list2], j++,
   AppendTo[squaredlist, list2[[j]]^2]];
  squaredlist]

sqList2[list]
```

> {1, 4, 9}

Alternatively `Map` could be used

```
sqList3[list3_List] := Map[#^2 &, list3]

sqList3[list]
```

> {1, 4, 9}

**Note**

This form of function, close to the one you tried, would not have worked because `list2` is an input variable and cannot be modified.

```
sqList2[list2_] := (
  For[j = 1, j <= Length[list2], j++,
   list2[[j]] = list2[[j]]^2];
  list2)
```

The minimal modification to make it work would be:-

```
sqList2[list2input_] := (
  list2 = list2input;
  For[j = 1, j <= Length[list2], j++,
   list2[[j]] = list2[[j]]^2];
  list2)
```

Also, `For` loops do not output running results; that's why the output needs to be collected inside the loop.

Comment: +1, but note that using `AppendTo` to build a long list is going to be slow. There are better alternatives (e.g. `Sow`/`Reap`).

Comment: Yes, If I was concerned about performance I would use a linked list, i.e.  `Module[{squaredlist = {}}, For[j = 1, j <= Length[list], j++,
  squaredlist = {squaredlist, list[[j]]^2}]; Flatten@squaredlist]`

Comment: If I was concerned about performance I wouldn't use an explicit loop at all.  `list^2`, job done.  I'm hesitating to give this answer a +1 'cos I think teaching newcomers to Mathematica to write loops is like teaching teenagers to use a filter when they learn to smoke.